# Why is O(2ⁿ) less complex than O(1)?

Tags: algorithm

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/big-o-notation-why-it-matters-and-why-it-doesnt-1674cfa8a23c/

> 4. Exponentials have greater complexity than polynomials as long as the coefficients are positive multiples of n
>
> O(2ⁿ) is more complex than O(n⁹⁹), but **O(2ⁿ) is actually less complex
> than O(1).** We generally take 2 as base for exponentials and logarithms
> because things tends to be binary in Computer Science, but exponents
> can be changed by changing the coefficients. If not specified, the
> base for logarithms is assumed to be 2.

I thought O(1) is the simplest in complexity.  Could anyone help me explain why O(2ⁿ) is less complex than O(1) ?

Comment: This image, from the exact same article, contradicts that statement, as it shows `O(2^n)` is "Horrible": https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/2021/06/1_KfZYFUT2OKfjekJlCeYvuQ.jpeg

Comment: Just checked the article. They simultaneously say that O(1) is less complex than O(log(n)), which is less complex than Polynomials, which is less complex than O(2^n), which is then said to be less complex than O(1). Bullsh*t. O(1) cannot be more complex than something that goes to infinity, because O(1) is **bounded**

Comment: @Dai you are right ! ha ha

Comment: @MateoVial Yes, I'm confused by this.  That's why I ask.  So I can confirm that the statement is not true, right ?

Comment: My general advice is to steer away from anything describing itself as a "coding camp" - no matter if it's free or charges tuition. IMO/YMMV/IANAL/etc. (I don't mean to get into a debate into the worthiness of nontraditional education, but I mean the name "coding camp" has been marred and sullied so much that any _good_ institution today won't use the name themselves, so it's only grifters and the like who still call themselves that, IME)

Comment: @DataT It's more of a https://cs.stackexchange.com/ question

Comment: @Dai Oh.. I don't know about CS.  Let me explore.

Comment: Another non-reputable source: Readers beware.

Comment: (If you include your argument to `[think] O(1) is the simplest`, your question was good. There may be an audience fitting better: [Which computer science/programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-site-fits))

Comment: The article is of low quality, and has fundamental mistakes all the way through it. For example, complexity does not measure how complex something is. O(n^2) is not normally pronounced "big O squared". And O(2^n) is not actually more complex than O(1), however you interpret "more complex than" (which is at the minimum sloppy language).

Comment: Can anyone refer me to a good / proper url so that I could learn Big-O ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Errata.  The author made an obvious mistake and you caught it.  It's not the only mistake in the article.  For example, I would expect `O(n*log(n))` to be the more appropriate complexity for sorting algorithms than the one they claim (quoted below).  Otherwise, you'd be able to sort a set without even seeing all of the data.

"`As complexity is often related to divide and conquer algorithms, O(log(n)) is generally a good complexity you can reach for sorting algorithms.`"

It might be worthwhile to try to contact the author and give him a heads up so he can correct it and avoid confusing anyone else with misinformation.

Comment: Can refer me to a good / proper url so that I could learn Big-O ?  Thanks.

Comment: Khan Academy does a quite thorough set of lessons giving a good sense of scope and context.  https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms#asymptotic-notation  I would also look at princeton.edu for solid content that has a bit more of an adult feel to its presentation.  This particular one is of less depth, but gets to the point quickly and clearly:  https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/